# Is R's pgeom function incorrect?

Tags: r, probability

Let's say I have an event that has a probability of 0.02 of occurring each time a button is pushed. I want to calculate the probability that the event will occur the 8th time someone presses a button.

I can calculate this manually with 0.98^7 * 0.02 as 0.017 but if I use `pgeom(q = 7, prob = 0.02)` in R I get 0.149237. How can this be? I'm sure I'm missing something but I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
dgeom(7, 0.02)
# returns 0.01736251
```

The geometric formula  `p*(1-p)^x` descibes the density function `dgeom`. `pgeom`, however, does not compute the density but the lower-tail of the distribution.